# In r/m8, r is r8 GPR, and in reg/m8, reg is r16/r32/r64 GPR in the intel manual?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu, intel

In Vol. 2A 3-5, in Intel Combined Manual PDF, Order Number: 325462-080US, June 2023.

3.1.1.3 Instruction Column in the Opcode Summary Table

This section has heading items which are *r/m8*, *r/m16*, *r/m32* and *r/m64*. For example,

> r/m8 - A byte operand that is either the contents of a byte general-purpose register (AL, CL, DL, BL, AH, CH, DH, BH, BPL, SPL, DIL, and SIL) or a byte from memory. Byte registers R8B - R15B are available using REX.R in 64-bit mode.

> r/m16 — A word general-purpose register or memory operand used for instructions whose operand-size attribute is 16 bits. The word general-purpose registers are: AX, CX, DX, BX, SP, BP, SI, DI. The contents of memory are found at the address provided by the effective address computation. Word registers R8W - R15W
> are available using REX.R in 64-bit mode.

> r/m32 — A doubleword general-purpose register or memory operand used for instructions whose operand-size attribute is 32 bits. The doubleword general-purpose registers are: EAX, ECX, EDX, EBX, ESP, EBP, ESI, EDI. The contents of memory are found at the address provided by the effective address computation. Doubleword registers R8D - R15D are available when using REX.R in 64-bit mode.

> r/m64 — A quadword general-purpose register or memory operand used for instructions whose operand-size attribute is 64 bits when using REX.W. Quadword general-purpose registers are: RAX, RBX, RCX, RDX, RDI, RSI, RBP, RSP, R8–R15; these are available only in 64-bit mode. The contents of memory are found at the address provided by the effective address computation.

Although there are *r/m8*, *r/m16*, *r/m32* and *r/m64*, there are NOT *reg/m8* nor *reg/m16* in this section.

But there is a *reg* heading item, as follows :

> reg - A general-purpose register used for instructions when the width of the register does not matter to the semantics of the operation of the instruction. The register can be r16, r32, or r64.

Therefore I think in *reg/m8* or *reg/m16*, *reg* represents a *r16/r32/r64* GPR and in any instruction which has these operands, the width of the register does not matter to the semantics of the operation of the instruction.

Therefore, I think as follows :

- In the case of r/m8, r represents a 8-bit GPR.
- In the case of r/m16, r represents a 16-bit GPR.
- In the case of r/m32, r represents a 32-bit GPR.
- In the case of r/m64, r represents a 64-bit GPR.
- In the case of reg/m8, reg represents a r16/r32/r64 GPR.
- In the case of reg/m16, reg represents a r16/r32/r64 GPR.

Is this a correct iterpretation ?

By the way, I think all instructions which have reg/m8 or reg/m16 operands are

```
PEXTRB reg/m8, xmm2, imm8 ; 66 0F 3A 14 /r ib
PEXTRW reg/m16, xmm, imm8 ; 66 0F 3A 15 /r ib
VMOVW xmm1, reg/m16 ; EVEX.128.66.MAP5.WIG 6E  /r
VMOVW reg/m16, xmm1 ; EVEX.128.66.MAP5.WIG 7E  /r
VPEXTRB reg/m8, xmm2, imm8 ; VEX.128.66.0F3A.W0 14 /r ib
VPEXTRB reg/m8, xmm2, imm8 ; EVEX.128.66.0F3A.WIG 14 /r ib
VPEXTRW reg/m16, xmm2, imm8 ; VEX.128.66.0F3A.W0 15 /r ib
VPEXTRW reg/m16, xmm2, imm8 ; EVEX.128.66.0F3A.WIG 15 /r ib
```

.

Comment: Yes, r/m8 is an 8-bit register or an 8-bit memory location.  And yes, a few instructions write a narrower operand with a memory destination than register, including vector extracts.  Also mov from segment register, but Intel documents that as `MOV r16/r32/m16, Sreg`  (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov).  (And Intel APX will finally introduce an EVEX encoding of SETcc that zero-extends to fill a GPR,  https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/advanced-performance-extensions-apx.html , over 20 years after AMD64 missed the chance to fix that design wart.)

Comment: For the `reg` instructions in your list, I don't think any of them will accept a 16-bit register operand.  You can specify a 32-bit or 64-bit register, but the encodings are the same because those instructions zero-extend anyway.

Comment: But for instance, `pextrb bx, xmm0, 3` is invalid and rejected by NASM.  It would suggest that the result is written into the `bx` register while leaving the upper 48 bits of `rbx` alone, and AFAIK there is no encoding with that effect.

Comment: By AMD manual, instructions obeying a general law of changing operand-size by a 0x66 prefix or a REX.W bit are basically limited to legacy general purpose instructions. But all instructions having reg/m8 or reg/m16 are above SSE which are not legacy instructions. Therefore, although semantically r16/r32/r64 are all accepted, instruction encoding are maybe the same. A "reg" heading item says that r16/r32/r64 are semantically the same in those instructions with "reg" operand.

Comment: Interrestingly, I found now PEXTRB reg/m8, xmm2, imm8, PEXTRD r/m32, xmm2, imm8, VPEXTRD r32/m32, xmm2, imm8, and PEXTRQ r/m64, xmm2, imm8. reg is used only in the case of m8(xxxB) but not m32(xxxD) nor m64(xxxQ). D or Q mov 32 bits or 64 bits. B movs 8 bits.

Comment: xxxB moves 8 bits to lower 8 bits of a destination register and zero-clears all upper bits. If r16 can be written in assembly code, it is inconsistent to AMD general rule that if the destination is r16, upper bits above lower 16 bits of the underlying register is preserved.

Comment: Right, only `pextrw` and `pextrb` write a memory operand that's narrower than 32-bit.  `pextrd`/`movd` and `pextrq`/`movq` (and the VEX versions) write a 32 or 64-bit operand, so they can just be documented as `r/m32` or `r/m64`, because writing a 32-bit register *always* zero-extends to the full register, [as Intel documents](//stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part).  Since `pextrb` and `pextrw` zero-extend with a register destination, they aren't documented as `r16` or `r/m16`.  (And `reg` doesn't include `r16` in this case)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by r16 being "semantically accepted".  It certainly *isn't* accepted in practice, and I don't think the manual meant to imply that it should be; it's just careless wording.  I suspect that they meant to say something like "The register can be r16, r32, or r64 *as appropriate to the instruction and the mode*".

Comment: My understanding has deepened a bit.

Comment: I am making assembler(compiler) that supports SSE/SSE2/SSE4/AVX2/AVX512. I do NOT know how to deal with reg/m8 or reg/m16 automatically nor know general rule about it.

Comment: Probablly, I think xxxB/xxxW instruction with a reg/m8 or reg/m16 destination should not accept r16 as a destination register.

Comment: As Peter Codes says about it already, I come to think it can't write r/m8 or r/m16 in the instruction columns if they want to keep AMD general rule.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge, although I used the word "semantically", I do not know the meaning of the word "semantically" deeply. Even I don't know what "semantically" means.

Comment: Incidentally, neither reg/m32 nor reg/m64 has been found in the instruction table in the intel manual(PDF). There are only reg/m8 and reg/m16, although I do not know the reason why deeply.

Comment: I have come to think that r32 is the most appropriate for reg in reg/m8 or reg/m16 now.